# What exactly should I do if I get an IOException in my servlet?

Tags: servlets, server-side, ioexception

So when I'm writing to an HttpServletResponse's Writer, it can throw an IOException for any number of reasons. I mean, we're dealing with sockets here, and there's lots of things that could go wrong. Timeouts, aborts, velociraptors, etc.

I was always taught you should never catch an exception unless you can do something about it. But I'm not sure that really makes sense here. If I've already started writing, and something goes wrong, I can't really trust that anything is going to make it to my client. But I can't throw that exception to a higher level, because it's a checked exception.

What do I do if I actually get an IOException when writing my response in a servlet?

Answer (score 1):

It is thrown for a reasone by Servlet service methods and its delegates.  Developer is not supposed to handle those exception thrown by servlet APIs.

This exceptions are thrown when some thing is not right some where else and on your code.

You definitely need to handel IOException when you are doing some explecete IO Activity not related to servlet api.

so I will do it this way.

```
Servlet{
    service throws ServletException, IOException {
        do some styff...
        do some styff...
        try{
            Doing some IO activity not related to Servlet api....
        }catch(IoException iox){
        }
        do some styff...
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.